# Iterate through the lines returned by grep in Shell

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I have a file info.txt. The first column is the id, and the rest are its content.

```
 1 aaa bbb
 1 ccc ddd mmm
 4 ccc eee
 7 ddd fff jjj kkk
```

I'm only intereted with the lines beginning with "1". So I use grep to filter it:

```
what_I_concern=$(cat info.txt | grep -iw 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-)
```

and then I want to iterate through these lines:

```
 for i in $what_I_concern; do
     pass $i to another program #I want to pass one line at a time
 done
```

But what it really did is to iterate through every word in these lines, instead of taking each line as a whole.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You take care about the *after* the number, so you cannot iterate over *every* word, but *every second*, right? To put it another way what is the format of the input you expect?

Answer (score 2):

The way you're trying to accomplish what you need is causing word splitting.  Instead, say:

```
while read -r line; do
  someprogram $(cut -d' ' -f2- <<< "$line")
done < <(grep '^1' info.txt)
```

---

The `<()` syntax is known as [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).  In this case, it enables the `while` loop to read the output of the `grep` command as a file.

Comment: Could you please explain the '<' before grep?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using `grep` and `cut` altogether in this case (assuming default `IFS`)

```
while read -r first rest; do
    [ "$first" = "1" ] && pass "$rest" to another program; 
done < info.txt
```